# How to draw arcs of arbitrary angle, or defined by tangents in Visio?

Tags: vector, shapes, microsoft-office

I am using MS Visio 2013, trying to draw a circular arc which spans between two 45 degrees lines. Think about an isosceles right triangle, where the head (90 deg) vertex is trimmed to a circular shape of a given radius.

The ultimate goal is to create a pincushion shape made of 4 such arcs. Here's my current shot (resized for showing details). It was made by drawing a 90 deg arc using the arc tool (from 0 deg to 90 deg), then rotating the shape, using the 3-D Z Rotation in 45 deg.

[image]

As you can see, the connection of the arcs with the diagonal sections is not smooth and overlapping.

**Questions:**

1. Can I draw an arc defined by its start and end angles?
2. Can I draw an arc defined by its start and end tangent lines?
3. Is there a pincushion shape hiding in one of the sets (it has the advantage of being opaque, and you can set the internal color)?

Finally, if you think there is a better SE site to ask this question, please point that out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So,  I noticed the "SEARCH" option in the Shapes pane. Searching for "arc", I found a few possible methods for achieving what I was looking for, for answering question #1. Specifically, the `Arc - graphical`, `Arc - numeric` and `Arc: 3pt.`.

I could not find a predefined pincushion shape.

Comment: This should be an update to your question, and not an answer, IMO.

Comment: @MichaelSchumacher - Why? It does answer (partially) the question.